Barplot of top DEGs after DESeq2
I am performing a meta-analysis and used ComBat-Seq for batch adjustment. The PCA plot indicated good data homogenization. I performed DESeq2, including tumor purity as a covariate. However, every time I try to visualize the top 10 DEGs, I notice that one sample consistently appears as an outlier. I attempted to exclude this sample from the analysis, but when I rerun DESeq2 and visualize the results, another sample becomes an outlier. Essentially, regardless of what I do, one sample always shows the highest intensity in visualized the dds.norm data.
Do you know why this is happening. I didn't realized the same effect without including tumor.purity as covariance (maybe it still exist but not so obvious).
Is it expected to be happened? Is there anything I can do?

I am comparing R/NR and I am expecting to see difference between two group, In this case it seems that whole statistics is driven by one outlier.
Code I used:
dds0 <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = count.table, colData = Pheno, design = ~Tumor.purity+ Pathological.response)
dds.norm <-  estimateSizeFactors(dds0)
sizeFactors(dds.norm)
## Performing estimation of dispersion parameter
dds.disp <- estimateDispersions(dds.norm)
alpha <- 0.0001
wald.test <- nbinomWaldTest(dds.disp)
res.DESeq2 <- results(wald.test, alpha=alpha, pAdjustMethod="BH")

#############################################################################################
png("Normalized counts plot.4.png", width=50, height=15, units="in", res=600)


par(mfrow = c(3, 3))  # 2 reda, 5 kolona
par(mar = c(4, 4, 8, 2))

gn.most.sign <- list()

for (i in 1:9) {

  gn.most.sign[[i]] <- rownames(res.DESeq2.pvalue.05.lfc.1)[i]`
  

  gn.most.diff.val <- counts(dds.norm, normalized=T)[gn.most.sign[[i]],]
  

  barplot(gn.most.diff.val, col=Pheno$Color2,  main=gn.most.sign[[i]], las=2, cex.names=0.5,)
}
dev.off()


It looks like you're new to SO; welcome to the community! If you want great answers quickly, it's best to make your question reproducible. This includes sample data like the output from dput() or reprex::reprex() and any libraries you are using. Check it out: making R reproducible questions.
